# Select In query how to order in where clause racle

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I have two tables.

This is my first query

```
select teacher_id from teacher a , stats s where s.type=25 and a.teacher_id=s.teacherP_id order by s.count desc;
```

My second query

```
select *from teacher where teacher_id IN (select teacherP_id from stats where type = 25);
```

In my java class, I am using hibernate

if i use first query, i can take teacher table coz i am just retuning teacher_id if i use select * i am gettin all fields from stats and teachers.

if i use second query i cant order them by count field.

How can i get just with one query all fields of teacher and ordered by stats count field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should learn explicit `join` syntax.  If you are learning SQL, a simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

Second, you can select all the columns from a table using `<table alias>.*`.  The following is the query you want:

```
select t.*
from teacher t join
     stats s
     on t.teach_id = s.teacherP_id
where s.type = 25 
order by s.count desc;
```

Comment: Thanks for you help Gordon, what to you mean with table alias?

Comment: `t` and `s` are table aliases.  These are abbreviations used for tables that are sometimes necessary, but generally useful to make queries easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 2):

Please try, if you could the following query:

`select a.* from teacher a , stats s where s.type=25 and a.teacher_id=s.teacherP_id order by s.count desc;`